# I can't import org.springframework.web

Tags: spring-mvc

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.Getmapping;
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home(){
        return "hone";
    }
}
```

I just can't import org.springframework.web so that I can't use @GetMapping.
How to solve this problem?
Should I add more dependencies?

Comment: why you can't? what error did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [`spring-web`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web) module to your classpath.

**`Gradle`**

```groovy
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '5.2.6.RELEASE'
```

**`Maven`**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `build.gradle`, under `dependencies`, add:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'

// TODO: Add this implementation
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-web:5.3.15'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Then, as shown below, be sure to 'Reload All Gradle Projects'.

For additional context, consult the [docs on Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web/5.3.15).

Essentially, we have to specify this source for our `import` to know from where to import.

It's not clear to me why this isn't part of the offerings whenever we use the [Spring Intializr](https://start.spring.io/). ‍♂️

[image: Click icon to 'Reload All Gradle Projects]